# Segmentation fault when running a simple nasm program on manjaro

Tags: nasm, manjaro

i'am trying to make a simple NASM program on Linux Manjaro 20.2, the code:

```
section .data
global _start

_start:
mov rax, 60
mov rdi, 0
syscall
```

and build it up with

```
nasm -f elf64 test.asm
ld -o test.out test.o
./test.out
```

but no matter what, it always outputs Segmentation fault.
On the other side, i tried it up on Linux Mint Ulyssa and the program exits perfectly.

Comment: Change `section .data` to `section .text`

Comment: oh wow, you right. Thank you so much, i'm not sure why it worked on mint. I'll accept your answer if you do